# Can I use Asynchronous code to fix StackOverflow error?

Tags: c#, wpf, error-handling

I am trying to make a Sudoku solver in C# WPF, using backtracking algorithm, everything was going smoothly, but just as it seemed like it was going to work, I started getting stack overflow errors.

I tried to fix them with separating the loops and calls, but I still am getting the same error.

Another thing I tried was to make certain methods separate threads, but that seems too complicated and I am not sure it will work.

I want to know if separating them with threads could work or if I have to do something else so I don't get the error.

The main part of the code is below, though I don't know if it can be of any help

```
// h is the current Label's index in the list MTLabels (Empty labels)
// a is the current number I am displaying

    private void Calculate()
    {
      Label label = MTLabels[h];

      label.Content = a;

      Check(label);
      return;
    }

    private void Check(Label label)
    {
      CommonLabels.Clear();
      var p1 = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(label) as UIElement;

      int labelID = Convert.ToInt32(label.Name.Substring(5));
      int labelY = GetLabelY(labelID);
      int labelX = labelID % 9;
      string labelParent = ((Grid)p1).Name;

      foreach (Label lbl in Labels)
      {
        if (lbl != label)
        {
          var p2 = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(lbl) as UIElement;
          int lblID = Convert.ToInt32(lbl.Name.Substring(5));
          int lblY = GetLabelY(lblID);
          int lblX = lblID % 9;
          string lblParent = ((Grid)p2).Name;

          if (lblY == labelY || lblX == labelX || lblParent == labelParent)
          {
            CommonLabels.Add(lbl);
          }
        }
      }

      CheckInCommon();
    }

    private void CheckInCommon()
    {
      Label label = MTLabels[h];
      foreach (Label lbl in CommonLabels)
      {
        if (lbl.Content.ToString() == label.Content.ToString())
        {
          if (a >= 9)
          {
            label.Content = "";
            h--;
            label = MTLabels[h];
            a = (int)label.Content;
            a++;
            label.Content = a;

            Check(label);
          }
          else if (a < 9)
          {
            a++;

            label.Content = a;

            CheckInCommon();
          }
        }
      }
      if (h + 1 < MTLabels.Count)
      {
        a = 1;
        h++;
        label = MTLabels[h];
        label.Content = a;

        Check(label);
      }
      else if (h + 1 == MTLabels.Count)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
      }
    }
```

Comment: No. Threading is not the issue. If you're getting stack overflow, you have a logical error in your code. CheckInCommon calls Check, and Check calls CheckIncommon. This will produce an infinite recursion. When using recursion to solve a problem, you have to have a condition that stops the recursion. And it's usually the first thing in the function (but not always.) The other thing is that your a and h values should probably be parameters to your functions somehow so you keep track of which spot in the soduku you're checking instead of rechecking the whole thing every time.

Comment: It might make your life easier to use a stack/queue/list instead of recursion

Comment: Oh okay, so in this case I would have to make a condition in the beginning of the functions to stop them? How can I implement that here?